# is sitecore media library a DAM?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore9, dam

I'm new to sitecore and I'm slightly confused whether their sitecore digital management is also known as sitecore media library? Or is it a completely different solutions/product?

We have sitecore 9.1

Comment: You can store and manage media in the Sitecore media libary, but if your looking for DAM, the Sitecore Content Hub is a beter choose. also connects seamlessly with Sitecore

Comment: And does it require different license? Primarily we looking for to store website images and videos.

Comment: Yes, it requires additional licensing. Contact your rep, they can fill you in with more details

Comment: For just storing website assets the media libary is fine. keep in mind default the media is stored in the SQL database, some GB is okay. up to million files, for large videos that are bigger than then upload limit xxMB you need to take some actions, increase upload limit / CDN

Comment: Thanks @JanBluemink, that helps a bit. quick question - In sitecore is there a way to get image outside website like an API or something? idea is to also use that image url for other apps like mobile.

Comment: After publishing an image it is available on a specifice url. or if you want to get a list of images from folder xxxx or any  selection you can use The OData Item Service. or with JSS also possible to use GraphQL, many options for mobil

Comment: This totally make sense now. Thanks @JanBluemink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your version number I'm assuming the "Sitecore" you have is what is called Sitecore Experience Platform (or XP for short). It is one of the multiple products Sitecore sells. The DAM product is part of something called "Sitecore Content Hub", a separate SaaS solution. The DAM and the media library are very different things.

You can find an overview of Content Hub here: https://www.sitecore.com/products/content-hub

Content Hub is a SaaS product, so you don't install it, as you would with XP. It does have integration into Sitecore Experience Platform, allowing you to use the assets in Content Hub within your web channel. You can think of Sitecore XP as the place your web channel puts together the content and layout as something that will be delivered. Content Hub is aimed more at the marketing team as a work area for them to create and manage various assets for all of their channels (web, mobile, email, print, etc.). The DAM part of Content Hub is specifically for media assets, but there are other parts of Content Hub that can be purchased as well.

As they are separate products, they are also licensed separately. A common scenario would be to have a marketing team working together on their workflow for their DAM assets in Content Hub and then sharing with the web team that is building the site via the Content Hub to XP integration.

Comment: This makes total sense now as i was getting confused with sitecore xp media library as "DAM" and was unable to find specific answer for it on internet.